# Display products by catalog using REST api in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, catalogsearch, rest-api

**Problem:**

I am trying to display products using below rest api with ref http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/rest/retrieve-filtered-responses.html

```
GET http://192.168.0.133/index.php/rest/V1/products/?searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=category_gear&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=8&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=finset&fields=items[sku,name]
```

I am getting response as

```
{
"items": null
}
```

Whereas I have 4 products in `category/catalog` with `id=8`

What is the correct way to call the `api` ?

I am using `magento 2.2.1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have read the doc again: `category_gear` is a product attribute. NOT belong to category attribute.

For example, I'm going to get product with category id 8

```
$searchCondition = "http://mage220.loc/rest/V1/products/?";
$searchCondition .= "searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=category_id&";
$searchCondition .= "searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=8&";
$searchCondition .= "searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=eq";
```

Search Criteria:

```
[search_criteria] => Array
        (
            [filter_groups] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [filters] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [field] => category_id
                                            [value] => 3
                                            [condition_type] => eq
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )
```

My Magento version is 2.2.0

**[Note]**

> the `searchCriteria` must be specified in the URL of the GET request.

Comment: Thanks.How should I know which are category attributes?

Comment: @Hiranya Log in into Admin > STORES > Attributes > Product. You can see it.